# how to display big table with MPDF?

Tags: php, mpdf

I have a recent problem with MPDF  . When am trying to display big table of 1000 rows the processing is very long more than 10 min and the server is crashing.  I have to stop the server at the end because it does not processing my table. I have look at this solution  on their forum  . I used the proposed solution but i still have the same problem. Can someone has encountered this  ? Please i need some help  .  Thanks

here is the proposed solution :

http://mpdf.bpm1.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=270

```
Reduced Memory Usage printing Tables
------------------------------------
mPDF uses a lot of memory when processing large tables. Parts of the script have been rewritten to 
reduce memory consumption when writing tables which use collapsed borders (10-25% saving).

Memory usage can be reduced further by setting a configurable variable:
$this->packTableData = true;  // default=false
but note that this causes a significant increase in processing time.
```

Comment: Is the number of rows per page constant? If so, just divide your data set by that constant and create one table per page.

Comment: no the number of page is not constant , am trying to do some report based on search criteria. All of the information  has to be in the pdf

Comment: Not the number of pages, the number of rows per page. If 1 page always has 50 rows and your table is 1000 rows, tell mpdf to create a 50 row table 20 times instead of a 1000 row table once which it apparently can't handle.

Comment: What version of mpdf are you using?  It looks like the project is a bit untended to. I found an unofficial github repo that looks fairly up-to-date: https://github.com/finwe/mpdf  but the forum post you reference is 3 years old, so maybe the newer version has fixed the issue? I would try it out.

Comment: Mpdf has a function WriteHTML that am using to render  the same html as pdf  . this is where i have the problem . can u just explain more what you mean ?

Comment: Am using mPDF 5.7 i will try to downlod the one you just proposed . thanks

Comment: Are you building the html table string first and then passing it to the `WriteHTML` method? Is the html table simple rows and columns (vs nested tables, etc).  If it's just `<tr><td>text</td><td>text</td></tr>`, you could create an html table for each page and pass them one by one to `WriteHTML`, that way, mpdf won't crash trying to parse/covert one giant table but instead will stop after each batch and allow any garbage collecting and memory clearing necessary.

Comment: Yes Am building the html table from an array and passed it to the `WriteHTML` to display it.

Answer (score 0):

**Blank pages or some sections missingPermalink**

If you pass a large chunk of code to WriteHTML() whether as CSS styles or the main HTML code, you may get a blank page output, or that section of code missing.

The PHP function preg_replace() has a maximum string length it will parse (by default this is often about 100000 characters). Over this, PHP silently returns a null value. So long strings of code will be replaced by nothing!

You may be able to increase the value of pcre.backtrack_limit at runtime if your system allows; alternatively, break your HTML into chunks and pass them one at a time to WriteHTML()

pcre.backtrack_limit is configurable from PHP >= 5.2.0

The default value was increased from 100,000 to 1,000,000 from PHP >= 5.3.7

***ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "1000000");***

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced the same issue with `mpdf`. It was too slow with a large table. In my case, the number of rows was 5000 and the execution time exceeded 60 seconds. For a web page, it's really slow. So, I start looking for another solution and I found [PHP WkHtmlToPdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf) composer package. It requires to install `wkhtmltopdf` and optionally `wkhtmltoimage` into the system. But, it's a lot faster than `mpdf` because it's not PHP library and build on Perl, I really recommend it for generating large pdfs.

PS. I know my answer will not help to solve the problem with `mpdf`, but I just shared my experience. I hope, it will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

exchange value $limit = ini_get('pcre.backtrack_limit'); to $limit = 5000000;

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.